# threejs build guide unclear

Tags: node.js, build, three.js

so i need to modify three.js.min and i need to rebuild it to have the changes take effect.

i did it before when it used to be via phyton, but the process & method seems to have changed.

i downloaded node.js as linked here in the quickstart guide: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Build-instructions, and restarted my pc

this happens when i try to clone threejs as described:[image]

the Quickstart says that i can also "download and unzip" the directory which i already did to work on it, but i am unsure where to place it and where the relative path starts.

so if i use `cd ./three.js` would the threejs folder be in the c:/programs/nodejs directory? do i need to register it first? am i on the completely wrong path?

sorry if this is a really dumb question, but the guide just does not make sense to me

Comment: if it makes any difference, i am on win 10 using nodejs v6.9.1

Answer (score 1):

ok so here are the mistakes i made:

- i used the Node.js command window (from programs) instead of the windows cmd
- i need to navigate to my threejs root folder containing the package.json file using cd ./nextFolder

now compiled & working without a problem